# How to handle optional properties with `satisfies` without losing the benefits of `satisfies`?

Tags: typescript

I'm using the `satisfies` operator to define a few objects (which are constants). The object's type has optional properties. Like

```js
// A type
type ObjectWithOptionals = {
  foo: string;
  bar?: string;
}

// One object that has the optional property
const example1 = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar"
} as const satisfies ObjectWithOptionals

// Two objects that do not
const example2a = {
  foo: "foo"
} as const satisfies ObjectWithOptionals

const example2b: ObjectWithOptionals = {
  foo: "foo"
}
```

I run into the issue of the error TS 2339, when I want to generically access the optional property:

```js
// Using the properties
const allBars = {
  example1: example1.bar ?? "barFallback",
  example2a: example2a.bar ?? "barFallback", // <-- errors
  example2b: example2b.bar ?? "barFallback", // <-- OK
}
```

The `example2a` object does not have the optional property and Typescript complains.

How should I handle such cases? It's especially an issue if I want to loop over such objects. For example, like this:

```js
const bars1 = [example1, example2a].map((example) => example.bar ?? "fallback") // fails
const bars2 = [example1, example2b].map((example) => example.bar ?? "fallback") // works
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AYxFu90sDpWcVd0ZiHrzLx9fsDwbzYfYkbZscpKRTIrFySTYAGEkZLCAA)

Maybe I should create an issue in the TS repo?

Comment: If you don't like how `satisfies` works you can always make your own helper function which does it the way you want, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NnEoow)... does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think this goes into the wrong direction where you need to provide more boilerplate to get where you want. I think I need to be more clear on what I mean with "benefits". 

With `satisfies` a single keyword does not unnecessarily generalize the type like in `example2b`. TypeScript knows that `example2a.foo` is the literal `"foo"` instead of just a string.

Also, we get that with a single keyword.

Comment: Sometimes you will need more code than you’d like if you want to change the default behavior of TypeScript. An identity helper function is fairly lightweight, all things considered. If your threshold is “no more code than a single keyword” then you’ve overconstrained the problem and the answer is likely to be “this is impossible”.  I won’t write up an answer you’re unlikely to accept, but you might want to recalibrate your expectations here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the TS compiler know that you want your object to be treated as ObjectWithOptionals in your given context.

You can use these 2 approaches:

1. - Give explicit type to mapped array

```ts
const allExamples: ObjectWithOptionals[] = [example1, example2a, example2b];
allExamples.map((example) => example.bar ?? "fallback")
```

2. - Use helper function with explicit parameter type

```ts
function getBarWithFallback(example: ObjectWithOptionals) {
  return example.bar ?? "fallback";
}

[example1, example2a, example2b].map(getBarWithFallback);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that makes sense. However, it creates the necessity to be explicit about the whole object/parameter said `ObjectWithOptionals` belongs to.

Comment: After trying out a few cases. The worst case would be to probably type the whole parameter. And that's only because I want a concise lambda. So I think the trade-off is good enough. However, I still feel that just because a field is not there, TypeScript should allow for fallbacks, because the value that should satisfiy the type could be a union. I probably need to make a clear example of that.